# What is the significance of ShardEngine related properties in sharding policy?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

Running `.show database <DB name> policy sharding` for an ADX cluster with V3 kusto engine returns the below result:

```
{
  "MaxRowCount": 750000,
  "MaxExtentSizeInMb": 1024,
  "MaxOriginalSizeInMb": 2048,
  "UseShardEngine": true,
  "ShardEngineMaxRowCount": 1048576,
  "ShardEngineMaxExtentSizeInMb": 8192,
  "ShardEngineMaxOriginalSizeInMb": 3072
}
```

What is the significance of the last four ShardEngine related json properties? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/shardingpolicy) do not mention them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties whose names start with `ShardEngine` apply when `UseShaedEngine` is true, i.e. to tables/databases that are using the v3 engine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/engine-v3

Eventually, the second set of properties, that apply to the previous version of the engine, would be removed from the policy.

Comment: Should ShardEngineMaxExtentSizeInMb be set lower than ShardEngineMaxOriginalSizeInMb, since in most cases compressed size would be smaller than uncompressed size? If yes, what should be their default values?

Comment: Both properties you mentioned serve as targets to different internal operations that you need not worry about. The strong recommendation is to keep the sharding policy with its default values, and not alter it.